# How to handle Window Azure's service failure in background services (azure Worker role)

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azureservicebus, high-availability, azure-redis-cache

One part of our application works as a "Rule engine". Rules can be configured on two factors: Process state and time. Rules can be simple or complex. Every rule has a status - True or False

A typical rule looks like this:

When- 
   Time between  9:00 and 11:00 and Process-1 Status is open.

```
And
```

Time is between 4:00 and 6:00 and Process-2 status is closed.

So, this rule needs to be checked and evaluated at 9:00, 11:00, 4:00 and 6:00, when process-1 state is changed, or process-2's state is changed.
After evaluation if rule status is changed (from previous one), we raise an event. New result is stored so that when next time this rule is evaluated, its result can be compared. If new result is same as previous one, nothing happens.

We used 3 different components in our application to achieve this same:

1) Web UI - To create Rules, change process state etc. It raises events whenever process state or Rule configuration is changed.

2) Scheduler - This is a worker role (window service) that runs a job every minute, It checks if there are any Rule where where start time or end time is current time, If found, It raise an event to a queue.

3) Rule Engine - This engine is worker role (window service) that listen to 3 kind of events: Rule's definition change event, process state change event and time event. In case of any process state change or time rule event, it find out all the rules which uses this as conditions, fire those rules and further raise event as "Rule state change".

This solution is built over Window Azure cloud platform. Here are few more design decision:

1) Rule's definition are stored in sql server. As mentioned earlier, rule can be hierarchical (complex) in nature and consist of multiple conditions.

2) Since extracting rules by time or Process1 from database could be a time consuming operation, We fetch all this data one time from sql database and stored in Redis cache. Keys are made such that we can find our all the rules by Time or Process Id. This operation is done when Rule engine starts. All Process's state are also stored in database and in cache.

3) Azure service bus is used to pass message from one component to another.

4) Whenever any master data is changed from Web UI, an event is passed on queue and Rule Engine update the cache.

System is designed keeping Auto-scaling in mind. If workload increases, queue depth will increase, and we can add more instance to rule engine.

Please suggest if you find any improvement in design desribed above.

Here are the problems we are facing in terms of High availability and component failure:

There are multiple azure services are used and all of them can fail at different time (Even if multiple instance are used):

1) Web UI (Web Role) 99.95 availability - This is not an concern as of now.

2) Scheduler (Worker Role) 99.95 availability

3) Rule Engine (Worker Role) 99.95 availability

4) Azure Service Bus 99.9 availability

5) Redis Cache 99.9 availability (no SLA on data)

Assuming everything is working fine, and all of a sudden any of the following situation arises:

Problem 1: User is changing Rule's definition from UI, system add this data to sql database, but service bus is not responding. We cannot communicate this change to Rule Engine and thus system will go out of sync.
    - One solution could be to rollback the DB operation and tell user to try again after some time.
    - Another option could be to have a two phase commit. If service bus is not responding, maintain a flag in database. Runs a background process which    push this change to queue whenever queue is available.

Problem 2: User is changing any Process's state, system add this to sql database, but service bus is not responding. This Process state change cannot communicate to Rule engine. Rule Engine will be out of sync.
    - Same as previous one.

Problem 3: Scheduler engine goes down: Time events are not raised and thus rule engine would not be able to work on those events.
    - We can log the time whenever a scheduler runs a job. Whenever a scheduler it should first raised all the missed event and then start executing new        ones.

Problem 4: While working on messages from Rule engine, Cache goes down. Rule engine cannot process messages on queue. This should be fine as we are not losing any message. But in case cache comes back, it might lose all the cache data as well. Rule engine will have to rebuild the cache (as it was done when Rule engine started).

Thanks for your time. I will be grateful if you can add any suggestion.